Is it more gas efficient to store a string literal or its bytes representation?
I am aware that it is generally discouraged to store strings on-chain. However, in case there is no way around this, I have a few questions regarding the gas and memory efficiency of storing strings directly on-chain versus converting them to bytes.
Here are my examples:
Example 1:
bytes memory private data;
function storeData(string memory _data) public {
    data = bytes(_data);
}

Example 2:
string memory private data;
function storeData(string memory _data) public {
    data = _data;
}

Example 3 (with the string being converted to bytes with ethers.toUtf8Bytes(str)):
bytes memory private data;
function storeData(bytes memory _data) public {
    data = _data;
}

As I understand it, bytes in Solidity is UTF-8 encoded, therefore examples 1 and 3 should cost the same except for the conversion cost. Is it generally advisable to store a string literal like in example 2, or are there more costs associated with storing a string directly on-chain, making example 3 preferable?

It is effectively the exact same thing.
The string type is just a byte array of UTF-8 encoded characters under the hood. The conversion work is done off chain by the web3 library you're using.
Also (and because of that), the conversion in example 1 would not generate any opcodes, it's purely syntactic sugar. You can easily test for that using remix if you want. In all 3 cases, storing "Hello World!" (or 0x48656c6c6f20576f726c6421, its hex representation) costs 45260 gas and retrieving it costs 3298 gas.
One thing that could be more efficient (especially if you're planning on storing longer strings) is to use more efficient packing or come up with your own and implement it in solidity (the standard english alphabet and punctuation can fit into 7 bits, when UTF8 uses 8). It would create overhead costs from the conversion to/from UTF-8 but that could be offset by the reduced storage cost for longer strings.

Is it also the same for converting bytes back to string?
If I want to return a string stored as bytes can I: return string(bStr) ?

Yep, same thing.
